# How would I configure REST uri to respond to this uri

Tags: java, rest, uri, jersey

The GET of the following is triggered with the following uri

/PathA/SomePathA

```
@Path("/PathA")
public class SubscriptionEntry 
{
  @Path("{PathA}") 
  public SomeType SomeMethod(@PathParam("parA") String userip) 
  {
            //This is called!!! with  /PathA/SomePathA 
           return new SomeResource(uriInfo,request,userip,httpreq);
  }
}
```

where SomeResource is something like this

```
public class SomeResource 
{
  @GET 
  public Type AnotherMethod
  {
        .....
        .....
  }

      @Path({"What is suppose to be here???? since this class has no name??}") 
      public MyType MyMethod()
      {.... 

      }


}
```

MY Question is how can i adjust the class above (What is needed in path) so that the MyMethod is triggered with uris like

/PathA/SomePathA/Test

or

/PathA/SomePathA/SomePathB/Test

I tried doing something like following but it does not work

```
@Path("/Test") 
      public MyType MyMethod() {}
```

Any suggestions on how i could make this work or what i am missing ??

Comment: What you've coded will not work: Jersey will scan annotations only once, and define the mapping URL <-> method only once. So when method is invoked, URL-to-method mapping already occurred. You re-route the method call, but for Jersey URL is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First, calling one resource from another resource would be wrong approach towards RESTful architecture.
Second, what you asked is not possible.

Instead, you should identify the relationships between the resources.Example:

- Class has many Students.
- Student belongs to a Class.

Then form your URLs accordingly. like

- **GET /class** --> Get all classes
- **GET /class/{id}** --> Get a particular class
- **GET /class/{id}/students** -->  Get students of particular class
- **GET /student** --> Get all students
- **GET /student/{id}** --> Get a mparticular student

[Here is nice article on URL design](http://redrata.com/restful-uri-design/)